# How to send a notification to a specific device using PARSE REST API with ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, api

Can I send a push-message within my app to only one specific device (probably with the device token ?) Instead of sending to all devices ?

Here is my code

```
    public static bool PushNotification(string pushMessage)
    {
        bool isPushMessageSend = false;

        string postString = "";
        string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
        var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);

        postString = "{ \"deviceType\": \"ios\"," +
                        "\"deviceToken\": \"xxxxxxxxxxx\"," +
                        "\"channels\": [\"\"], " +
                         "\"data\" : {\"alert\":\"" + pushMessage + "\"}" +
                         "}";

        httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
        httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "My Parse App Id");
        httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", "My Rest API Key");
        httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
        StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
        requestWriter.Write(postString);
        requestWriter.Close();
        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            JObject jObjRes = JObject.Parse(responseText);
            if (Convert.ToString(jObjRes).IndexOf("true") != -1)
            {
                isPushMessageSend = true;
            }
        }

        return isPushMessageSend;
    }
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202945(v=vs.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation, you can send notifications to queries. And queries can get the specific device with given id.

Code below is curl equivalent:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: APP_ID" \
-H "X-Parse-REST-API-Key: API_KEY" \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{
      "where": {
      "installationId": "ca100000-ec00-0000-0000-000000000000"
    },
    "data": {
      "alert": "Special delivery! Just for you!"
    }
  }' \
```

https://api.parse.com/1/push

I tried it with my real credentials, and it worked. Hope you can implement the C# version of it.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks SafaOrhan, it works using C#:

```
private bool PushNotification(string pushMessage)
{
      bool isPushMessageSend = false;

      string urlpath = "https://api.parse.com/1/push";
      var httpWebRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(urlpath);

      string postString = "{ \"where\": { \"installationId\": \"DEVICE-INSTALATION-ID\" }, \"data\": { \"alert\": \"Special delivery! Just for you!\" } }";

      httpWebRequest.ContentType = "application/json";
      httpWebRequest.ContentLength = postString.Length;
      httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-Application-Id", "YOUR APP KEY");
      httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("X-Parse-REST-API-KEY", "YOUR REST API KEY");
      httpWebRequest.Method = "POST";
      StreamWriter requestWriter = new StreamWriter(httpWebRequest.GetRequestStream());
      requestWriter.Write(postString);
      requestWriter.Close();
      var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpWebRequest.GetResponse();
      using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
      {
           var responseText = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
           JObject jObjRes = JObject.Parse(responseText);
           if (Convert.ToString(jObjRes).IndexOf("true") != -1)
           {
                isPushMessageSend = true;
           }
      }

      return isPushMessageSend;
 }
```